# Bug in owl carousel, line break slides

Tags: jquery, line-breaks, owl-carousel-2

I found a strange problem, help understand this problem owl plugin or I did not do right.
See the [example on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jtap/pzrnzf2v/3/), if we replace 'Красная поляна111' to 'Красная поляна' (remove 111) - will transfer the slide line. 
If set `loop: true;` - all good.
Why is that?

```
<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
 <div class="item"><h4>Имеретинская низменность</h4></div>
 <div class="item"><h4>Красная поляна111</h4></div>
</div>

$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
 loop: false,
 dots: false,
 nav: false,
 margin: 20,
 singleItem: true,
 items: 1,
 autoWidth: true
})
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? I don't understand it to be honest. Also your fiddle works fine for me. Same behaviour in both cases.

Answer (score 1):

Can you please try below code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    loop: false,
    dots: false,
    nav: false,
    margin: 20,
    singleItem: true,
    items: 1
  });
});
```